# How to create variables dynamically in OCaml?

Tags: dynamic, ocaml

I am new to OCaml. I want to create new variables dynamically in a loop.

I tried few like x.(i), x.i, and tried to create names using fprintf.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you show us your code and exactly what you're trying to attempt? Are you sure you understand how cycling is done in functional programming?

Answer (score 2):

You can't: OCaml is a static language in which the number, scope and name of variables is fixed. If you want a way to dynamically map strings to values, use a hashtable or map.